# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'index'

Tags: php, database

I am a newcomer programmer . I have just started learning php . At this moment I try to make log in page . For log-in , I have the following code named "index.php":

```
 <!-- LOGIN FORM in: admin/index.php -->
<form method="post" action="restricted.php">
    <p><label for="u_name">username:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="u_name" value=""></p>

    <p><label for="u_pass">password:</label></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="u_pass" value=""></p>

    <p><button type="submit" name="go">log me in</button></p>
</form>
<!-- A paragraph to display eventual errors -->
<p><strong><?php if(isset($error)){echo $error;}  ?></strong></p>

<?php #admin/index.php 
           #####[make sure you put this code before any html output]#####

//connect to server
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or 
           die('could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error());

//select db
mysqli_select_db($dbc, 'simple_login') or die('no db connection');

//check if the login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['go'])){
    #####form submitted, check data...#####

        //step 1a: sanitise and store data into vars (storing encrypted password)
    $usr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, htmlentities($_POST['u_name']));
    $psw = SHA1($_POST['u_pass']) ; //using SHA1() to encrypt passwords  

        //step2: create query to check if username and password match
    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$usr' AND pass='$psw'  ";

    //step3: run the query and store result
    $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
//
    //make sure we have a positive result
    if($res!=false){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res)== 1 ){
            #########  LOGGING IN  ##########
            //starting a session  
            session_start();

            //creating a log SESSION VARIABLE that will persist through pages   
            $_SESSION['log'] = 'in';

            //redirecting to restricted page
            header('location:restricted.php');
        } else
        {
            //create an error message   
            $error = 'Wrong details. Please try again'; 
        }
    }
}//end isset go
?> 
<!-- HTML FORM GOES HERE -->
```

Then I have written the following code in a php page named "restricted.php" . The code for this page is as follows :

```
<?php #admin/restricted.php 
           #####[make sure you put this code before any html output]#####

//starting the session
session_start();

//checking if a log SESSION VARIABLE has been set
if( !isset($_SESSION['log']) || ($_SESSION['log'] != 'in') ){
        //if the user is not allowed, display a message and a link to go back to login page
    echo "You are not allowed. <a href="index.php">back to login page</a>";

        //then abort the script
    exit();
}

/**
*      ####  CODE FOR LOG OUT #### click here to see the logout tutorial 
*/

?> 
<!-- RESTRICTED PAGE HTML GOES HERE -->
```

But after giving jusername and password file the browser shows me the following error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'index' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\restricted.php on line 10
```

Why this error occurred ? How can I solve this issue ? Plz help me

Comment: `echo "You are not allowed. <a href="index.php">back to login page</a>";` change to `echo 'You are not allowed. <a href="index.php">back to login page</a>';`.

Comment: ^ Single quotes instead of double, since you have double quotes within your string already.

Comment: Yes . I got it . Thank you Dave .

Comment: Please, learn how to use prepared statements. Just because you replaces "mysql_" with "mysqli_" **does not** make you code better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the syntax highlighting, you need to escape the quotes in your HTML like this:

```
echo "You are not allowed. <a href=\"index.php\">back to login page</a>";
```

Or use single quotes instead of double quotes around the whole thing like this:

```
echo 'You are not allowed. <a href="index.php">back to login page</a>';
```